# The Industrialization of Earth and the Effect on Magic

Tags: magic, alternate-history, earth-like

I am currently writing a story that takes place after what we would call World War Three, in a post-war setting. In this setting, magic exists along with creatures created by radiation from WW3 and magic. Many kingdoms and settlements exist along the Post-War Earth.

In the story's history, four main time periods exist: the Early Period (pre-history period), the Exposition Period (we live in this period), the Pre-War Period and then the Post-War period. This question mainly focuses on the Early Period going into the Exposition Period. During the Early Period, magic existed on Earth and all forms of life could use magic in it's raw form. Humans were able to refine magic and use it to their advantage, creating towns, agriculture and etc. This use of magic swiftly lead to advancements in technology and the beginning of industrialization.

As humans began to use the valuable resources that Earth had to offer, magic slowly began to disappear. This lead to the eventual loss of magic and the memory of it.

Would it be plausible to say that the Earth absorbed the magic it held to keep itself alive and that's why it all disappeared? Would it be safe to say that magic that is held within objects like crystals or tomes would not be affected by the Earth?

Comment: Please refer to [this meta post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/how-to-deal-with-please-develop-my-high-concept-questions) on why we don't do high concept questions here.

Comment: I disagree @Ash.  If the OP was asking for help embellishing their high concept then I think you would be right on all points.  But in this case, they are just doing a sanity check on whether crystals and tomes which were presumably enchanted prior to magic becoming scarce would still remain charged.  I personally wouldn't have shared such an original high concept for such a reality check, but now that it has been offered to the public, the damage is done.

Comment: Have you read any of Larry Niven's series about The Magic Goes Away? There are several short stories and some novels. The key story was where a wizard discovered a spell that completely consumed all of the magic in a local area. Lots of fun with various magic entities and magic features fading most places, but flaring up quite alarmingly when some pocket of magic is released.

Comment: This are really pointless question fort WB SE as it's up t the OP to define their magic system to operate in whatever (hopefully self consistent) way that they want.  Any question asking if something magic is plausible needs to define a system and framework to use a reference for plausibility.  You don't provide that magic framework so it's pointless asking WB SE to judge it.  The only question is why Earth can "use" magic when it seems it's otherwise limited to living creatures to use it.

Comment: The problem here is that it is your magic, and therefore your rules. Does your story require the tomes and crystals to still work? If so, they're safe from the draining effect. Otherwise you can just handwave some rules about them needing to be periodically recharged, and as the recharging mechanisms no longer work the items just stop working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it plausible?  Sure.  Your universe... your rules.

Is it believable to the average reader?   It depends on how you spin it.

Crystals are no problem.  People tend to think of Magical Crystals a batteries, so there is already a great real world analogy for your situation.  When you don't pay your power bill and the lights in your home go out, the batteries in your flash lights still work.  So crystals should be no problem.

Tomes are a little more challenging.  Most readers equate tomes with instruction manuals.  When a magic user opens a tome and crafts a spell, it is not the book that is providing the power.  The book is just guiding the user on where to get the power from and what to do with it.  So in this case, the analogy breaks down.  Opening an instruction manual on how to operate a blender is not going to accomplish anything if your house electricity is turned off.

As your world's creator, you have the authority to change that and make tomes into a form of battery, but why swim up stream against reader expectations.  There are enough unavoidable challenges in creating a world.  No need to invite more.

Comment: The ink used in the tomes could be made using those very same crystals. This would allow the tomes to be both the instructions and the power source for each spell.